# Using Gurobi solver in the Enthought Canopy Editor on Linux

Tags: ipython, enthought, gurobi

I am currently working with Gurobi solver using python. Previously, I have just been using a mix of a text editor and the terminal to write and run my models but I am currently experimenting with using Enthought Canopy Editor. I have a model that is works when I run in in the terminal using `python model.py` but when I try doing`%run model.py` in Canopy's iPython shell I get:

```
%run /home/cdhagmann/Copy/Code_Env/Farmer/model.py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/cdhagmann/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.1.1189.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    181             else:
    182                 filename = fname
--> 183             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/home/cdhagmann/Copy/Code_Env/Farmer/model.py in <module>()
----> 1 from gurobipy import *
      2 from data_IO import read_data,currency
      3 import time
      4 
      5 # Import model data

ImportError: No module named gurobipy
```

My guess is that the terminal and Canopy look for modules in different places but I don't know how to rectify it. I found this reference on the Gurobi group site about [Enthought Canopy and Gurobi on OS X 10.8](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gurobi/ArCkf4a40uU) but didn't know how much those instruction would differ from doing it on Linux and even what he meant about installing Gurobi in Canopy's site-packages.

**UPDATE:** Based on information found the first link I clicked on, I did in fact leave the boxed clicked making Canopy my default directory. You have to manually prepend the PATH variable, which I missed them saying that I had to do. So I did that. I now have Canopy's version of iPython running in my terminal (check by using sys.path); however, I get a huge list of errors when I try run python.

```
cdhagmann@Crispin ~ $ python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 563, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 545, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 272, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 247, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 237, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 578, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 505, in get_config_vars
    import re
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 105, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 14, in <module>
    import sre_parse
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 17, in <module>
    from sre_constants import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py", line 18, in <module>
    from _sre import MAXREPEAT
ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
```

Suggestions?

And to answer @Jonathan questions:

`sys.prefix` = `'/usr'`

`sys.path`:

- `/usr/lib/python2.7`
- `/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu`
- `/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk`
- `/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old`
- `/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload`
- `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`
- `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`
- `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat`
- `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0`
- `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7`
- `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client`

`gurobipy.__file__`  =  `'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gurobipy/gurobipy.so'`

Answer (score 1):

If the terminal is correctly configured for Canopy Python, then python in terminal and Canopy Python should be looking for modules in the same places. If during installation, you disabled "make Canopy be default Python", or if you have not restarted terminal since installation, then it won't automatically be configured correctly.

These articles should help you understand and configure:

http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/configure/faq.html#where-are-all-of-the-python-packages-in-my-user-python-environment

https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-s-Python-be-your-default-Python-i-e-on-the-PATH-

https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-Python-from-the-command-line

If these articles do not suffice for you to solve this, then please report -- when you run python from terminal, what are these?

```
sys.prefix
sys.path
gurobipy.__file__
```

Comment: I did what it said in the articles. I now have the Canopy's version of iPython in the terminal (checked with sys.path) but it brings up a slew of errors if I try to run python now.

Comment: I don't know why it won't let me @ you, @Jonathan, but any more ideas?

Comment: Without detail, "slew of errors" doesn't give anything to analyze.

Comment: I edited the question with the "slew of errors" as I couldn't in the comment area.

Comment: I have also include the `sys.prefix`, `sys.path`, and `gurobipy.__file_` for you like you wanted, @Jonathan.

Comment: In the terminal, you are running another (system?) Python, not Canopy Python, so that's where you installed gurobi. Please read the above-linked articles, and follow the instructions in the 2nd article "Make Canopy's Python be your default...."

Comment: Sorry, my last comment was not sufficiently responsive. You say " I now have Canopy's version of iPython running in my terminal (check by using sys.path)" but the sys.path and sys.prefix that you display show no sign of canopy python. If you had successfully set Canopy Python to be default, then your sys.prefix would be "~/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User" or equivalent, the same as it is from within Canopy python.

Comment: I removed Enthought from the pathsince I must have a working python shell to work in and it was giving me the above errors when I tried to use python. IPython worked with Enthought in the path, and I verified that by using sys.path in an iPython environment.

Comment: I cannot install gurobi in Canopy if Canopy python isn't working.